# How to change size of turtle with custom shape?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to change the size of a turtle in Python, but with a custom shape.

I've tried looking on the internet, but I haven't found anything on changing the shape *and* changing the size.

```py
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.register_shape('image.gif')
wn.shape('image.gif')
wn.turtlesize(2,2,2)
```

All that does is change my shape to `image.gif`, without changing the size.

It works if I do `turtle.turtlesize(2,2,2)` to change the size of a turtle, but it doesn't work for me when I use a registered shape with it.

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289534/is-there-any-way-to-resize-a-gif-shape-with-turtle-in-python) link mostly answers my question, but I need there to be an easier way to resize it than making lots of new shapes...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to resize a gif shape with turtle in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289534/is-there-any-way-to-resize-a-gif-shape-with-turtle-in-python). Seems there isn't a way to do it solely in turtle, however you can use a bit of a Tkinter hack to make it work.